# Connected App - Profiles vs. Permission Sets

Tags: profile, metadata, connected-apps, permission-sets

Two scenarios for my questions below...

1. Permission Set named **XYZ** has a 2GP Connected App called **ABC** as an **Assigned Connected App** (in the Setup UI)
2. Connected App **ABC** (if Admin approved users are pre-authorized is set) has **Special User** Profile associated.

Questions:

1. Would a user who has been assigned the **XYZ** Permission Set (but not the **Special User** Profile) have the same access to Connected App **ABC** as a different user who has the **Special User** Profile but not the Permission Set **XYZ**?
2. I am not seeing a way in the PermissionSet metadata to set Assigned Connected App like we can in the Setup UI. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would a user who has been assigned the XYZ Permission Set (but not the Special User Profile) have the same access to Connected App ABC as a different user who has the Special User Profile but not the Permission Set XYZ?

Yes. However, note that is only true if Special User Profile is set in the org which is using the Connected App. These permissions aren't inherited from the source metadata.

> I am not seeing a way in the PermissionSet metadata to set Assigned Connected App like we can in the Setup UI. Is there a way to do this?

Retrieve the ConnectedApp from the org that you wish to configure, and you'll find the `permissionSetName` and `profileName` attributes that you can use to add or remove permission sets and profiles, respectively.

Comment: After associating two profiles and a permission set with the ConnectedApp in my scratch org, I tried retrieving the metadata for it and unfortunately no permissionSetName or profileName attributes were present. I'm guessing this is because it's a 2GP (which has that wonky approach for Connected Apps).

Also, to confirm... there are no metadata attributes on PermissionSet or Profile for Connected Apps (only attributes on ConnectedApp at least for connected apps that are not in 2GP).